# JUnit 5 with Kotlin and Spring Boot: How to properly use a custom test extension with dependency injection?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, junit5

I'm currently trying to set up a JUnit 5 test in Kotlin using Spring Boot and a custom test extension for a fake authentication service. The test extension is meant to set up and tear down the test environment for the authentication service, but I'm having issues with dependency injection.

Here's my test setup:

```
@ExtendWith(FakeAuthService::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=false"])
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = TestConstructor.AutowireMode.ALL)
class MyTest {
  // ...
}
```

And here's my FakeAuthService class:

```
@Component
class FakeAuthService : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    @Value("\${userendpoint.url}")
    private lateinit var url: String
    
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // set up the test environment
        // ...
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // tear down the test environment
        // ...
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that dependency injection is not working properly in FakeAuthService, and I'm getting an UninitializedPropertyAccessException when trying to access the url property.

Can anyone help me understand how to properly use a custom test extension with dependency injection in JUnit 5 with Kotlin and Spring Boot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programatically regeristering the extension instead seems to work (I guess since spring has already injected the values by then)

So:

```
    @RegisterExtension
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var fakeAuthService: FakeAuthService
```

and not:

```
@ExtendWith(FakeAuthService::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyTest {
```

Comment: Having the extension being autowired seems to be the game changer. I tried with just ˋRegisterExtensionˋ and it did not work. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that what you want to do is not possible - at least not like that.
The reason is that Jupiter extensions have a lifecycle that is completely detached from Spring's component lifecycle. Therefore an extension cannot serve as a component and cannot be on the receiving end of value injection.

I currently see one feasible options: Use reflection within your extension

The example is in Java, but you'll manage to translate it into Kotlin.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;
import org.junit.platform.commons.support.*;

class FakeAuthService implements BeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Optional<String> optionalUrl = getInjectedField(context, "url", String.class);
        optionalUrl.ifPresent(url -> {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the url
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        });
    }

    private static <T> Optional<T> getInjectedField(
        ExtensionContext context,
        String fieldName,
        Class<T> fieldType
    ) {
        Object testInstance = context.getRequiredTestInstance();
        Optional<Field> urlField = ReflectionSupport.findFields(
            testInstance.getClass(),
            field -> field.getName().equals(fieldName),
            HierarchyTraversalMode.BOTTOM_UP
        ).stream().findFirst();

        return urlField.map(field -> {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return fieldType.cast(field.get(testInstance));
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Retrieving member values in a generic way is a bit involved, but you can write your own little utility for that.

Alternatively, your test class could implement an interface - eg. `HasURL` - for retrieving the injected value(s). Then your extension could cast the test instance to this interface and get the value(s) from there. This probably looks a bit nicer, but restricts the usage of your extension to test classes that implement this interface.

**Update**: Although this answer works I like the solution in the other answer using
`@RegisterExtension` together with `@Autowired` better.

Comment: Is this something that has changed from Junit 4?

Then we had our fake servers implement the ExternalResource interface and then in the tests they were added like:

`
    @Autowired
    @Rule
    lateinit var emailServer: FakeEmailService
`

And the resource in question looked like this:
`
@Component
class FakeEmailService(val config: EmailConfig) : ExternalResource()
...
`

It is this similar behavior I want to achieve in Junit 5. Is it possible? Your way seems a lot more involved than how it was done previously.

Comment: Yes, lifecycle handling is completely different from JUnit4.